# Kafka simple producer not sending messages and not giving an error

Tags: python, json, serialization, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am writing a simple producer i just want to send raw data into a topic. for some reason i need to specify serialiser that will convert the message to json then to utf-8 then send in a json message..

this code doesn't work (no error but nothing to consume in the topic)

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
topic = "my_new_topic5"

producer.send(topic, b'test message')
```

this code works

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                     value_serializer=lambda x:
                     dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

for e in range(2):
    data = {'number': e}
    producer.send('numtest', value=data)
    sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to also call `producer.flush()` after `send()` and `producer.close()` before terminating your program. The following should do the trick:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
topic = "my_new_topic5"

producer.send(topic, b'test message')
producer.flush()
producer.close()
```

Comment: thanks flush worked, just wondering is it good practice to send in bytes like i am doing or should i use a string serializer?

Answer (score -1):

if you using windows machine then there is a problem
to follow quickstart,I did struggle 2 days
solution: you need to set kafka_home and all the command you need to run under the window directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).